# CakePHP Cookie/Session problems

Tags: internet-explorer, session, cakephp, cookies, cakephp-1.3

I am having issues with my CakePHP application. This seems to be happenining only in IE, and only on certain computers. It is consistent on the computers where it is happening though.

**Issue one:**
User is logged in and on the page https://example.com/users/view and clicks sign out. User is redirected to http://example.com and appears to be logged out until the user visits another https page and they are still logged in. They can click log out as many times as they want but they are always logged in on https and only get logged out on http.

**Issue two:**
User logs in at https://example.com/users/signin they are redirected to http://example.com and now appear to be logged in. User goes to https://example.com/admin/slides and does not know it yet but is now logged out, clicking on any other page (or just refreshing their current page) will ask them to log in again.

I have no idea whats going on. I have read and tried the solutions described on both these similar issues: [Session not saving when moving from ssl to non-ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308659/session-not-saving-when-moving-from-ssl-to-non-ssl) and [Cookie not renewing/overwriting in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577026/cookie-not-renewing-overwriting-in-ie) but I am still having the same problems.

The only clue I have noticed so far, (and I don't know if this means anything) is when I debug  both `$_SESSION` and `$this->Session->read()` on HTTP pages ALWAYS only $this->Session->read() returns a value. on HTTPS pages some ALWAYS return the same value for both, others ALWAYS only return a value for $this->Session->read().

For example, http://example.com and https://example.com/users never sees $_SESSION, https://example.com/carts always sees $_SESSION. I am not sure but I am thinking that maybe the secure pages are supposed to be seeing it and since some can't maybe something is wrong, however when I inspect the code I see no difference that would suggest why one does and one doesn't.

Also, if I add `$this->Session->destroy()` to the beforeFilter in AppController, then all pages even HTTP can see $_SESSION. I am not actually use $_SESSION in my application, I just thought this might be a clue to whats wrong.

---

**UPDATE**

I tooked Gustav Bertram's advice and looked at the user agent string. I compared the user agent string with IE on a computer that was having the issue to IE on a computer that was not having the issue. They were the same except the one that was having problems has "google chrome frame" in the user agent string. I uninstalled Google Chrome Frame from that computer, restarted, tried again and the problem seemed to be solved.

If this is the true cause, then the simple solution would be to make users uninstall Chrome frame. However I wonder if there is a work around that would allow them to have chrome frame installed and still work.

Comment: (I presume you've knocked out the usual caching suspects.) Which versions of IE? Does tinkering with the page headers (cache-control, etc - see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067) have any impact?

Comment: Is the session content scrambled or anything? Could be security options..

Comment: Is the page having any flash content ? Have you tried with changing session security from HIGH to LOW ?

Comment: @satyrwilder I don't beleive its the pages caching, everything thats dynamic works fine.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz I am not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: @Binoy Yes I have Security.level set to low in my core.php unless there is another setting I am unaware of?

Comment: @JohnIsaacks I've had problems with the suhosin security patchs and Sessions/cookies when they're encrypted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724289/cakephp-cookies-getting-scrambled-suhosin-related

Comment: @JohnIsaacks In this situation it's the browser's caching behavior, most likely specifically IE8's caching behavior (it handles directives differently, big surprise) that might be causing the issue? Even if the dynamic content appears to be "working" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568826/php-database-session-handling-problem-in-ie8 and http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079477/cakephp-session-is-lost-after-an-oauth-redirect

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try adding the following to your core.php file:

```
Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);
Configure::write('Session.ini',array('session.cookie_secure' => false, 'session.referer_check' => false));
```

These parameters should force the cookie to persist even through Google Chrome Frame.  This will set both PHP and CakePHP's settings to allow cookies to persist over http and https.

Comment: Thought I would mention that these are CakePHP 2.0 parameters.  They may be a little different in 1.3, but should allow you to navigate between http and https while logged in.

Comment: It looks like the same syntax as 1.3, worked in 1.3 with no errors. :) This does seem to fix the issue even when chrome frame is installed. Do you know why Cake was checking the agent in the first place? Sorry I already gave the bounty away it was about to run out when I did.

Comment: It's a security measure. I think that by default, it wants a secure cookie to only be valid in a secure connection.  If you go to http, then it's not secure anymore.  So, here, we are basically turning that off. No worries on the bounty.  Glad you got it working!

Comment: @ScottHarwell Will these settings have any impact on application security?

Comment: @DavidYell The solution wouldn't be the security issue, in my opinion. The security issue would come from passing a logged-in user between http and https.  One should relegate all traffic to https to maintain proper security, making this question / solution unneeded.

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion is that you take a look at the packets directly, to see what is happening to the cookies.

Install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on your client machine, and connect to a remote web server. (Wireshark will ignore localhost traffic.)

My suspicion is that your cookies are either getting mangled (I once had some cookies mangled by PHP!) or they are stuck (which would be IE's fault). Either way, you will have more information about what's going wrong.

As a last resort, check the user-agent string in the code for the offending / unsupported version of IE, and urge people to upgrade.

Comment: I am awarding you the bounty since your suggestion of looking at the user agent is what led to me finding the chrome frame issue. I would still like to figure out a way to get it to work with chrome frame installed though.

Comment: Apparently you can insert a tag to [force IE with Google Chrome to use the Chrome rendering engine](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/google/google-chrome-frame-hijacks-ie-and-is-now-considered-stable/2485). If that doesn't give you joy, it may be bug report time.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your AppController's beforeFilter and see if it does anything. I have a feeling the cookie settings aren't configured like you need. [See here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Cookies.html) for more info.

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Cookie->domain = '.example.com';
    $this->Cookie->secure = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you made sure you don't have any spaces or newlines after closing php ?> tag? Perhaps it was the first thing you checked, but from experience I know that badly closed php tags does cause sporadic problems with php session handling.